# NoReverseMatch: with arguments '()' and keyword arguments

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 1.5 and trying to pass args to my URL. When I use the first two args then the below code works fine, with the third args I am getting an error. I have already referred to the new Django 1.5 update for `url` usage and accordingly used quotes for the URL name.

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add_trip' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'city': 537, u'score': 537, u'time': 35703, u'distance': 1196.61}' not found
```

**urls.py**

```python
url(
    r'^add/(?P<city>\w+)/(?P<score>\w+)/(?P<distance>\w+)/(?P<time>\w+)$',
    'trips.views.add_trip',
    name='add_trip'
),
```

**html file**

```html
<a href="{% url "add_trip" city=data.city score=data.score distance=data.distance time=data.time%}">Add/delete</a>
```

If I use only two args (i.e city and score, then it works fine) else I get the no reverse match error.

**views.py**

```python
def SearchTrips(request):
    city = request.POST['city'].replace(" ","%20")
    location = request.POST['location'].replace(" ","%20")
    duration = request.POST['duration']
    #url = "http://blankket-mk8te7kbzv.elasticbeanstalk.com/getroutes?city=%s&location=%s&duration=%s" % (city, location, duration)
    url= "http://blankket-mk8te7kbzv.elasticbeanstalk.com/getroutes?city=New%20York%20City&location=Park%20Avenue&duration=10"
    print url

    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except:
        resp = None

    if resp:
        datas = json.load(resp)
    else:
        datas = None

    return render(request, 'searchtrips.html', {'datas': datas})
```

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: I think there is some issue with the regx, if I pass "score" to all the args then I am not getting this error.

Comment: i think `data.time` does not meet `\w+` format. Double check that.

Comment: time here is in seconds, its like an integer. I think there are issues with distance - as it is in decimal. How do I change the regx for distance in the URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance value `1196.61` does not match the regex because of the decimal point.

You can use

```
(?P<distance>[\w\.]+)
```

which matches uppercase A-Z, lowercase a-z, digits 0-9, hyphens and decimal points.

Alternatively, you could use

```
(?P<distance>[\d\.]+)
```

Which only matches digits 0-9 and decimal points.